# How to proxy requests to api.twitter.com including SSL certificates?

Tags: android, ssl, twitter, ssl-certificate

I'm using Twitter's new [Fabric SDK](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android) for Android. I've set up [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) as a proxy on my Mac so I can analyse the JSON payload in the API responses.

SSL proxying in Charles is enabled and access granted for my test device.

However, Charles shows me the following error for any request to Twitter:

> **URL**   https://api.twitter.com
>
> **Status**    Failed
>
> **Failure**   SSLHandshake: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Logcat shows me:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.   

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:306)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:241)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:174)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:120)

Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:318)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.PinningTrustManager.checkSystemTrust(PinningTrustManager.java:117)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.PinningTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(PinningTrustManager.java:160)
```

It looks to me like I need to trust some certificates...
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install a certificate on your phone to trust Charles?  I did something similar successfully with Fiddler: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForAndroid

Comment: Sure, official Charles certificate is installed: http://charlesproxy.com/charles.crt

Comment: Then you should get a notification warning (in Lollipop) that another application source is monitoring your network traffic.  If you don't get that notification, then something is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The Fabric SDK uses SSL Certificate Pinning to ensure that they are talking directly to the Twitter servers. Unfortunately, ***this means that you won't be able to view the traffic going between Fabric and the Twitter backend***.

Generally, standard SSL merely requires that a given certificate is "trusted." That's why you are able to trust the Charles certificate in your emulator or on your test device and then the networking stack won't complain. However, when a library is using SSL certificate pinning it won't trust just *any* trusted certificate but only a certain set of certificates. So even though your emulator is seeing a trusted Charles certificate, the Twitter library will fail unless is sees the actual Twitter API certificate. See more https://www.infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/securing-mobile-banking-on-android-with-ssl-certificate-pinning

If you **need** to see the traffic, you will need to use a Twitter library that doesn't use SSL Certificate Pinning.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks for the clarification. So what is your suggested approach for analysing response headers and/or JSON structure?

Comment: I am having the same issue with Fiddler2 setup.  My network requests are totally blocked in my android app now!